VBA - how to use latexmk
I'm trying to create a .pdf using VBA code. (I've written .tex by itself and now trying to marry them with the pricelist available in Excel).
I've downloaded LatexMk from https://ctan.org/pkg/latexmk.
I've created a Command Button on a sheet.
I've copied text from internet search:
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim latexmkPath As String
    Dim inputFilePath As String
    Dim outputFilePath As String
    Dim args As String
    
    ' Set paths and arguments
    latexmkPath = "C:\Users\CP\Documents\2411\Pricelist\latexmk\latexmk.pl"
    inputFilePath = "C:\Users\CP\Documents\2411\Pricelist\input.tex"
    outputFilePath = "C:\Users\CP\Documents\2411\Pricelist\output.pdf"
    args = "-pdf -pdflatex " & inputFilePath
    
    ' Execute LaTeXmk using Shell
    Dim shell As Object
    Set shell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    shell.Run latexmkPath & " " & args, 1, True
    
    ' Parse output file (e.g., open PDF)
    ' ... your code here ...
End Sub

I've created really simple .tex file and can run it by hand.
\documentclass[a4paper,12p]{article}

%%% select the required data %%%%
% select customer name
\newcommand{\company} {Test Company} 

\begin{document}

Testing for \company.

\end{document}

However, if running, I get this error:

together with "How do you want to open the file?"
Questions:

What is wrong in the code?
What is the script trying to open - what else do I need to download for it to work?


@K J: I can open the .tex file with your second reference CreateObject("Shell.Application").Open ("C:\Users\CP\Documents\2411\Pricelist\input.tex"); however it doesn't run it. One step closer

You are correct that msgbox appears in line latexmkPath. If just shell.Run latexmkPath, then it asked which application; however, internet search said: that downloading latexmk will also download PERL - I'm guessing not. How do I fix it?

Your code re RetVal doesn't run as Retval needs to be declared as something - I tried Object, but that gives error.
